# Can't reproduce XSS on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm trying to test for vulnerabilities in my website. There is a textbox in which I enter the value as follows:

`Dummy" /><script>document.alert('XSS Vulnerable');</script><input title="DummyAgain`

so that the HTML formed after submitting the form would be

`<input name="customerName" size="16" value="Dummy" /><script>document.alert('XSS Vulnerable');</script><input title="DummyAgain" type="text">`

But even though, the HTML formed is correct, the javascript does not execute and inspecting the element in firefox/chrome shows the value of the textbox to be exactly the same as I entered!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wondering... How comes the first `"` gets escaped as `&quot;` but neither other `"` nor any `<` get escaped? Is it a real scenario?

Comment: I'm sorry... I guess that happened while copying.. from Firefox.. none of the quotes is escaped.

Answer (score 2):

If you run this:

```
document.alert('XSS Vulnerable');
```

... you get this error message:

> TypeError: document.alert is not a function

This happens because [`alert()` is a method of the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert), not the `document` object.

You can also omit the object and it'll default to `window`:

```
alert('XSS Vulnerable');
```

**Update:** Reproduce code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input name="customerName" size="16" value="Dummy" /><script>window.alert('XSS Vulnerable');</script><input title="DummyAgain" type="text">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this as well.. no change in the status... basically.. the textbox contains whatever value I typed inside it. Where as it should contain only `Dummy`

Comment: You must be omitting something then. If you paste the code you gave in a HTML document, you get the JavaScript executed.

Answer (score 1):

For that code to be able to cause an XSS problem the `"` cannot be replaced with `&quot;` as it is in your example output.

Comment: That happened while copying the text from Firefox's inspect element box. Edited now. None of the quotes is replaced with &quot; in the HTML source.

Comment: @inquizitive — Are you looking at the source or are you looking at the inspect element data? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Basically, if the script executes, the textbox should contain only `Dummy`. However, currently it contains the same value which I entered.

Comment: @inquizitive - In case Quentin's comment wasn't clear, the only way to see *actual* HTML is the View->Source menu (Ctrl+U on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys..I was just checking the Inspect element feature in Firefox and Chrome, assuming this and view source was same... When I view the source I saw the value as `Dummy&quot; /&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;XSS Vulnerable&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;text`.

Sorry to bother you guys without checking the source!
Thanks @Quentin...